# Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k}$ Where $a_k=\sum_{m=1}^{k} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+m}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I showed that:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+{1 \over {k}}}} \leq a_k \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+{1 \over {k^2}}}}$$

And then
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k} \leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+{1 \over {k^2}}}}} \leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+{1 \over {n^2}}}}} =\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+{1 \over {n^2}}})^{2n}}} =1$$

And on the other hand:

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k} \geq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+{1 \over {k}}}}} \geq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+{1 \over {1}}}}} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt2}} =0$$

So

$$0 \leq \lim\limits_{n\to \infty}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n}a_k} \leq 1$$

But this inequality is actually trivial since  $0 \leq a_k \leq 1$.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but you can take logarithms and work with an infinite series instead of product.

Answer (score 3):

Notice
$$a_k = \sum_{m=1}^k \frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+m}} 
\le \sum_{m=1}^k \int_{m-1}^m \frac{dx}{\sqrt{k^2+x}}
= \int_0^k \frac{dx}{\sqrt{k^2+x}}\\
= 2 \left[\sqrt{k^2+x}\right]_0^k = 2\left(\sqrt{k^2+k}-k\right) = 2 \frac{\sqrt{1+1/k} - 1}{1/k}$$
If one make a plot of $2\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{x}$ versus $e^{-x/6}$ over the interval $[0,1]$, one will notice

$$2\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-1}{x} \le e^{-x/6} \quad\text{ for } x \in [0,1]$$
This leads to an upper bound for $a_k$:
$$a_k \le e^{-k/6} \quad\text{ for } k \ge 1$$
and hence an upper bound for the partial products.
$$\prod_{k=1}^N a_k \le \exp\left(-\frac16\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{1}{k}\right) \le \exp\left(-\frac16 \log N\right) = N^{-\frac16}$$
As a result, $$\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^N a_k = 0$$